# Uso de Spinner no Android

Tags: android

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação *Android*, e nela eu tenho um `Spinner` e a partir da escolha que o usuário fizer nesse `Spinner` ele vai para determinada página.

Eu tinha feito assim:

```
//Acionando_Items_no_Spinner
public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() 
{
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
}
public void addListenerOnButton() 
{
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);//Informação_Do_Spinner
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);//Informação_Do_Botão
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Escolha_da_pagina
            if(String.valueOf("São Paulo") != null){  
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_page2);
            }else{
                if(String.valueOf("Rio de Janeiro") != null){  
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page3);
                }
            }

        }
    });
}
```

No principio funcionava, mas quando tem mais de uma opção, como mostra no código acima, ele entra no primeiro `if` e mesmo se estiver errado ele da o resultado do primeiro `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O fato de ele sempre entrar no primeiro `if` é que String.valueOf é sempre diferente de `null`.

Acredito que o que queira fazer é o `if` em relação ao item do `Spinner` e para isso precisa fazer a seguinte alteração:

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);//Informação_Do_Spinner
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);//Informação_Do_Botão

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String valorDoSpinner = spinner1..getSelectedItem().toString();
            //Escolha_da_pagina
            if(valorDoSpinner.equals("São Paulo")){  
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_page2);
            }else if(valorDoSpinner.equals("Rio de Janeiro")){  
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_page3);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Além disso há outro problema não mencionado, não é possível chamar `setContentView` após já ter chamado no `onCreate`. Precisará iniciar outra `Activity` usando `Intent` ou partir para o uso de `Fragments`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, tu simplificou bem, eu tava vendo outros jeitos bem mais difíceis. Obrigado